# A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found

Tags: .net-core

When I run my WPF application on other computers it throws me this error:

```
Description: A .NET Core application failed.
Application: program.exe
Path: C:\fakepath\program.exe
Message: A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in 
[C:\fakepath\].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [C:\Program 
Files\dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or 
register the runtime location in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].
```

Add library runtime 3.1.0 it help me.

Comment: I had this issue with test project on Azure. I had to add a step to install runtime at the beginning of a pipeline.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Further to Ajith's answer, "Deployment Mode: Self Contained" can also be selected in Visual Studio 2019 here:

[image: GUI in Visual Studio]

Comment: Doing this throws ´System.PlatformNotSupportedException´ in my case

Comment: I need to run console application exe another windows 10 machine which was not exist .net framework which was published in VS 2019.  But I couldn't run it. same error occurred. What should I do?AdanSandoval

Comment: Self contained, oddly enough, didn't fix it for me by itself.  If you click Show all settings -> File publish options, I had to also check "Produce Single File" and "Enable ReadyToRun compilation" and then it worked.

Comment: @DanCsharpster - Yes, that did the trick for me, too. But - it created 60 MB exe file for my 30 line console app. I was building my other little console apps in Visual Studio 2008 until now, and just grabbing a few KBs files. This is quite a surprise ...

Comment: @Marek, its putting all of the libraries you might possibly need to run it into one file.  That didn't quite surprise me, but it was annoying.

Answer (score 31):

I got the same error for my .Net core 3.0 app today. This is because you are missing the .net core run time in the machine, and is installing a framework dependent application.

The solution for this is to publish the application with Deployment Mode Self Contained.

Use the below command to publish from command line

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r <RID> --self-contained true
```

get the RID details  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#windows-rids

Comment: I am building my program with `msbuild` instead of `dotnet publish` do you happen to know the flag to turn on Deployment Mode Self Contained?

Answer (score 21):

My solution to avoid "hostfxr.dll missing" in a framework-dependent application was to install the the "Hosting Bundle" on the target computer.

The ASP.NET Core Runtime enables you to run existing web/server applications. On Windows, we recommended installing the Hosting Bundle, which includes the .NET Core Runtime and IIS support.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.12-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Comment: Here in 2021 this was the easiest, least complicated, solution.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, install Hosting Bundle and it works for me. 
Thanks

Comment: September 2023.

Answer (score 7):

As from the error message, if this is a [framework-dependent application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) :

```
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [C:\Program 
Files\dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or 
register the runtime location in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].
```

Please set the DOTNET_ROOT environment to one of the following locations, depending upon where you have installed `dotnet.exe`

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet OR C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet
```

from "My Computer | Properties | Advanced | Environment Variables". Now restart your IDE/Terminal whatever you are using.

Comment: I have wasted a week of evenings trying to work out issue where NUnit was not working, wish I could give you 10 votes. Nunit and .NET Core working now

Answer (score 3):

For some weird reason .net publisher failed to publish self-contained .Net Core 3 application (console app). I've solved this just installing .Net Core 3 Runtime on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up on this page many times in my search for a solution to my problem.

My self contained exe was raising the error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.1
```

I was publishing the .net core 3.1 runtime and referencing a netstandard library that referenced System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.1

The following git hub page has this marked as a known issue
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1-known-issues.md#net-core-312

Setting our exe to publish the .net core 3.0 runtime fixed this for us.
We have control of the referenced library so will probably follow the advice on the github page but for anyone else that has not got control of library may find this of use.

Answer (score 0):

EntityFrameWork Core has been moved out of the dotnet sdk you need to install dependency globally check progr C:\Users"Your User Name".dotnet\tools.store\dotnet-ef\3.1.5 if it was present you have sucessfully installed EFcore globally and make sure your project level Ef Core dependency version matching with globally installed EFcore version .....if there is a mismatch it will trow above error...if you uninstalled make sure you are deleting the above path folder C:\Users"Your User Name".dotnet\ and again reinstalling....It will Worked for me